# Excel VBA: Having trouble understanding Loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops

My code can be seen below.
I have set `TacticInput` and `DateInput` as a Range (it finds the first visible cell after filtering).

I then want it to enter `CodeTextBox` into the range `TacticInput` but only if its empty.
If its not empty I want to offset by 2 columns and then try again, if that is not empty aswell I want it to keep trying until it successfully finds an empty cell and assigns it to `CodeTextBox`.

The same with `DateBox`: Enter it into `DateInput` if its empty, if not, offset by 2 columns and try again and repeat.

This is the code I have managed to come up with but its not working. I've tried quite a few different combinations but I'm stuck.
Currently it just replaces the value in the first column, it does not find the next empty cell and put it there.

```html
Dim TacticInput As Range
Dim DateInput As Range
Dim TrueValue As Boolean

Set TacticInput = Sheets("Sheet1").Range([B2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AL")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1)
Set DateInput = Sheets("Sheet1").Range([C2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AL")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1)


TrueValue = False
Do Until TrueValue = True
    If TacticInput = "<>" Then
        TacticInput.Offset(0, 2) = TacticInput
        DateInput.Offset(0, 2) = DateInput
    Else
        TacticInput = CodeTextBox.Value
        DateInput = DateBox.Value
        TrueValue = True
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `If TacticInput = "<>"` doesn't test if the cell is not blank.  You should use `isempty` instead:

```
If not isempty(TacticInput.Offset(0, i)) Then
```

Also, when you perform the offset, I would expect that you would get a runtime error.  You want a `set` there as well so that you are changing which range is being referred to.

```
If TacticInput = "<>" Then
    Set TacticInput = TacticInput.Offset(0, 2)
    Set DateInput = DateInput.Offset(0, 2)
```

Comment: I changed    If TacticInput = "<>" to If not isempty(TacticInput.Offset(0, i)) Then and it works for the first input but the next time I try it my excel crash. Could you explain what you mean by SET the offset?

Comment: @MikaelSelander Take a look at the second block of code.  I had a copy/paste typo.

Comment: Thanks! But a new error this time: "424" Object Required. It points to this line: Set TacticInput.Offset(0, 2) = TacticInput Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, another typo.  It has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need a loop for this necessarily. Instead, you could use `Find` to get the last available empty cell in that range, then use that to define the cell the values should be written to. Example:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rInput As Range
    Dim LastCol As Long

    Set rInput = Sheets("Sheet1").Range([B2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AL")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    LastCol = rInput.Rows(1).Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    If LastCol Mod 2 = 0 Then
        LastCol = LastCol + 2
    Else
        LastCol = LastCol + 1
    End If

    Cells(rInput.Cells(1, 1).Row, LastCol).Value = CodeTextBox.Value
    Cells(rInput.Cells(1, 1).Row, (LastCol + 1)).Value = DateBox.Value

End Sub
```

Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Only if he wanted the new values to be entered in between data that's already there. I'm assuming all cells in the `rInput` right of the data are blank, waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you wrote `If TacticInput = "<>" Then`: in this case TacticInput is probably never equal to a string in which the followin characters <> are located. You may have wanted to write `If TacticInput = ""` which is the very contrary of `If TacticInput <> ""`

You could try a very simple loop:

```
i = 0

Do Until IsEmpty(YourRange.Offset(i,0))
    i = i + 2
Loop

YourRange.Offset(i,0) = "Write what you want here"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I thought that "<>" was an expression that meant anything besides empty. Is that incorrect?

Comment: As previously said if you need "anything but" you use <> (without "") as an operator, like +, -, = and so on... When you use "" you are basically saying that you want to insert a string which is whatever is contained in the ""

Answer (score -3):

Try,

```
Dim i as long
TrueValue = False
i = 0

Do Until TrueValue = True
    If TacticInput.Offset(0, i) Is Nothing Then
        TacticInput.Offset(0, i) = CodeTextBox.Value
        DateInput.Offset(0, i) = DateBox.Value
        TrueValue = True
    Else
        i = i + 2
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: I get the error "Run-time error "1004": Application-defined or object defined error. It points to this line:     If TacticInput.Offset(0, i) Is Nothing Then

Comment: `Is Nothing` tests whether an object has been set, but does not say anything about what the value of the object is.

Comment: My mistake. Should be If IsEmpty(TacticInput.offset(0, i)) Then

Comment: I could not get it to work and the response above gave me an answer. I appreciate your help!